# Spring Batch job flow wait for some user action

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a test Spring Batch flow job:

```
@Bean
    public Job reportJob() {
        //@formatter:off
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get(REPORT_JOB_NAME)
                    .flow(step1())
                        .on("*").to(waitForAdminApproval())
                            .on("*").to(step2())
                    .end().build();
        //@formatter:on
    }
```

After step1() I need to wait for manual actions(approval) by website admin and only after that to move to ste2.

How it can be implemented with Spring Batch flow job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend to do it this way. Define two different Jobs which can be launched indepedently.

Comment: So, I'll start the other job after admin approval and so on ?

Comment: Yes. There is no concept "wait for user input" in spring-batch. You start a job, it will run and eventually ending in state FAILED or COMPLETED. If you need a control instance a layer above that, you need to use a kind of jobcontrol system or implement your own. Depending on your needs, you could probably use spring-integration for that. Note: I'm not saying you can't put this into the same application. You could write a main class, that starts the first job, waits for its termination, waits for "AdminApproval" and then starts the second job.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need.